# Class 'Registry' not found in Open cart1.5.4

Tags: php, opencart

I am new in open cart. I did configuration good in config.php file but when I try to open my open cart project in browser, it gives me error as below,

### Fatal error: Class 'Registry' not found in D:\wamp\www\tileandstone\admin\index.php on line 24

I am using php `PHP Version 5.4.16` please help me. I know, I left something but I don't know what. Help me please. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's not given a file not found error for the registry engine file, it's likely the file is simply corrupted. Re-upload `/system/engine/registry.php`

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem. I had smth like that:

### Fatal error: Class 'Document' not found in ...index.php on line 194

My solution was in deleting all files in **vqmod/vqcache** folder.

Comment: thanks it's works for me but after some time when vqcache file is genrated this error comes again any solution for that . ? i am new for opencart so please help me